# R lag/lead - how to ignore rows before and after existing rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lag, lead

I have this dataframe in R

```
   id      a        b        c        d
1  42      3        2       NA        5
2  42     NA        6       NA        6
3  42      1       NA        7        8
```

With function like this

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>%
 mutate(e = lead(d))
```

I get at third row NA since there is not fourth row, but how can I get value from first row - 5? Result should look like this

```
   id      a        b        c        d         e
1  42      3        2       NA        5         6
2  42     NA        6       NA        6         8
3  42      1       NA        7        8         5
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `first` function in the `default` argument of the `lead` function.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(e = lead(d, default = first(d)))
dat2
#   id  a  b  c d e
# 1 42  3  2 NA 5 6
# 2 42 NA  6 NA 6 8
# 3 42  1 NA  7 8 5
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   id      a        b        c        d
1  42      3        2       NA        5
2  42     NA        6       NA        6
3  42      1       NA        7        8",
                  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there a benefit of using `first(d)` over `d[1]` or is it personal preference?

Comment: @Lyngbakr I think it is personal preference.